# Why PowerMock use javassist libraray and Mockito is not use

Tags: mockito, powermock

I don't understand why PowerMock use javassist library and Mockito is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the conversations about code generation libraries in Java circle around three libraries: cglib, javassist, and ByteBuddy. Mockito was formerly on cglib, but now uses ByteBuddy as its default code generator.

As ByteBuddy author Rafael Winterhalter [notes here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32412928/1426891):

> javassist offers an API for modifying classes and not only for subclassing them. These APIs allow also for byte code-level manipulation while cglib only allows for several hardcoded interceptions.

Though I am not a contributor on any of these mocking frameworks or libraries, it's worth noting that Powermock works in part by editing class implementations to intercept calls to private, static, and final methods and classes within compiled bytecode. This likely explains the requirement to use javassist from Powermock: cglib was not capable of editing existing classes. Mockito, in contrast, needs simpler code generation in order to generate a subclass of the given class; this is functionality that cglib and ByteBuddy were written to provide.

Note that [open Powermock issue 727](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/727) tracks an incomplete migration of Powermock from Javassist to ByteBuddy.

Now, the reverse: Why doesn't Mockito switch to Javassist instead of ByteBuddy? Again, we don't have a direct answer, but [the ByteBuddy tutorial expresses an opinion](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) (under "General Information" for Javassist, emphasis mine):

> This library comes with a compiler that takes strings containing Java source code which are translated into Java byte code during the runtime of an application. This is very ambitious and in principle a great idea since Java source code is obviously a great way for describing Java classes. **However, the Javassist compiler does not compare to the javac compiler in its functionality and allows for easy mistakes when dynamically composing strings to implement more complex logic.** Additionally, Javassist comes with a proxy library which is similar to the JCL's proxy utilities but allows extending classes and is not limited to interfaces. **The scope of Javassist's proxy tools remain however equally limited in its API and functionality.**

In short: There is anecdotal reason to doubt Javassist's safety/functionality/stability. Mockito did not require Javassist's features, so it could migrate straight from cglib to ByteBuddy. PowerMock did require Javassist's features, and the efforts to migrate PowerMock to ByteBuddy are stalled and ongoing.